# is it possible to set the preservesPitch property for the <audio> tag in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

I know you can set it in javascript

```
const audio = document.querySelector("audio");
audio.preservesPitch = false;
```

but is it possible to set it directly in HTML? something like:

```
<audio
  controls
  loop
  preservespitch="false"
  src="audio.mp3"
/>
```

I'm trying to use as less javascript as possible, so I would like to set it in the html tag.
This documentation only shows how to do it with javascript https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/preservesPitch